# C3.js Hide tooltip when value is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, linechart, c3.js

So I am using C3 to create a line chart which looks like this:
[image]

Now I have to hide the tooltip when the value on the chart is zero. I can't find any solutions online or on the documentation of C3.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `tooltip.contents` function for that. It modifies the HTML of the tooltip according to your needs.

According to *the docs*:

> **tooltip.contents**
>
> Specified function receives `data, defaultTitleFormat,
>   defaultValueFormat` and `color` of the data point to show. If
>   `tooltip.grouped` is `true`, `data` includes multiple data points.

The documentation explains it clearly here: [C3 Docs - Tooltip Contents](https://c3js.org/reference.html#tooltip-contents)

You can see an example on this fiddle I made: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/diegovincent/y45wLdq6/)

Hope I could help!